# Reasons for a script tag to throw an error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, alpine.js, adblock

I'm currently using the following script (with AlpineJS directives) tag to check for an ad blocker. However, regarding to user feedback, this sometimes results in a false positive. What could be the reason for this?

```js
<script async @abort="ad.blocked = undefined" @error="ad.blocked = 'VisX'" :src="`https://s.visx.net/tag.js`"></script>
```

Comment: That's not a simple `<script>` tag; something is interpreting those `@` attributes.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, it's interpreted by AlpineJS